# Why foreign key is created as unsigned when adding it to an existing table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I quite new to Laravel and have 2 tables in **phpMyAdmin** which are `cars` and `owners`, I want to add the `owner_id` column to the `cars` table as a foreign key, so what I did is I ran this line in terminal:

```
php artisan make:migration alter_table_cars_add_foreign_key
```

Then I modified the new generated migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('cars', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreignId(column:'owner_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('cars', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropForeign(['owner_id']);
        });
    }
};
```

So the column is added to the `cars` table, but it is not a foreign key but `UNSIGNED`

[image]

How to make it as a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

`UNSIGNED` means that you cannot insert negative integer values. Table IDs cannot be negative, so it adds this type of value to save memory. To add value as foreign key, you need to add `->constrained` to your migration ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)).

```
Schema::create('examples', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
   $table->timestamps();
});
```